# synchronize README in git or files between branches

Tags: git, synchronization, branch

i want to synchronize my README file in all branches.

- is there a way without submodules?
- can i use for the purpose of
  synchronizing the git hooks (.git/hooks)?

have you faced the same problem?
how have you solved it?

thanks for helping and joining

Update:
Let me give you an example. I have my company1 Branch and now i have created a company2 Branch, if I Update the Readme file in Branch C2 then the Readme file should Update also in Branch C1. Without merging :)

Comment: You should post some additional information about what repos you have set up and for what purpose you are trying to "synchronize" things

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you maybe haven't added the file to git and you are missing some fundamentals of how Git works.  What happens if you do `git status`?  Does README show up under "Untracked files"